# C++ potentially-throwing code at COM method boundaries

Tags: c++, winapi, exception, com, windows-shell

C++ exceptions can't cross COM module boundaries.

So, assume **we are in a COM method body**, and some C++ *potentially-throwing* method/function is called (this can throw because e.g. STL classes are used):

```
STDMETHODIMP CSomeComServer::DoSomething()
{
    CppDoSomething(); // <--- This may throw C++ exceptions
    return S_OK;
}
```

**Q1.** Is the above code a viable implementation?
For example, if that code is part of a context menu shell extension, if the C++ `CppDoSomething()` function throws a C++ exception, what does Explorer do? Does it catch the C++ exception and unload the shell extension? Does it just crash Explorer (making it possible to analyze the problem using a crash dump) following a *fail-fast* approach?

**Q2.** Would an implementation like this be better?

```
STDMETHODIMP CSomeComServer::DoSomething()
{
    //
    // Wrap the potentially-throwing C++ code call in a safe try/catch block.
    // C++ exceptions are caught and transformed to HRESULTs.
    //
    try
    {
        CppDoSomething(); // <--- This may throw C++ exceptions
        return S_OK;
    }
    //
    // Map C++ std::bad_alloc exception to E_OUTOFMEMORY HRESULT.
    //
    catch(const std::bad_alloc& ex)
    {
        // ... Log the exception what() message somewhere, 
        // e.g. using OutputDebugString().
        ....
        return E_OUTOFMEMORY;
    }
    //
    // Map C++ std::exception exception to generic E_FAIL.
    //
    catch(const std::exception& ex)
    {
        // ... Log the exception what() message somewhere, 
        // e.g. using OutputDebugString().
        ....
        return E_FAIL;
    }
}
```

**Q3.** Or would it be even better, if a C++ exception is thrown, to just set an internal flag (e.g. a `bool m_invalid` data member) to put the COM server in a state such that it can't work anymore, so every successive call to its method returns some error code, like `E_FAIL` or some other specific error?

**Q4.** Finally, assuming that Q2/Q3 are good implementation guidelines, it's possible to hide the verbose `try/catch` guard in some convenient preprocessor macros (that can be reused in every COM method body), e.g.

```
#define COM_EXCEPTION_GUARD_BEGIN  try \
                                   {

#define COM_EXCEPTION_GUARD_END    return S_OK; \
                                   } \
                                   catch(const std::bad_alloc& ex) \
                                   { \
                                       .... \
                                       return E_OUTOFMEMORY; \
                                   } \
                                   catch(const std::exception& ex) \
                                   { \
                                       .... \
                                       return E_FAIL; \
                                   }

// 
// May also add other mappings, like std::invalid_argument --> E_INVALIDARG ...
//

STDMETHODIMP CSomeComServer::DoSomething()
{
    COM_EXCEPTION_GUARD_BEGIN

    CppDoSomething(); // <--- This may throw C++ exceptions

    COM_EXCEPTION_GUARD_END
}

STDMETHODIMP CSomeComServer::DoSomethingElse()
{
    COM_EXCEPTION_GUARD_BEGIN

    CppDoSomethingElse(); // <--- This may throw C++ exceptions

    COM_EXCEPTION_GUARD_END
}
```

Using modern C++11/14, is it possible to replace the aforementioned preprocessor macros with something else, more convenient, more elegant, just better?

Comment: *Never* throw C++ exceptions (or near-any other type) across a COM boundary. That is what the HRESULT is for. If you want more information consider The `IErrorInfo` and `ISupportsErrorInfo` paradigm. Regarding the macros in your last snippet, thats a design decision on your part, but one way or another, *don't throw out of a COM member*.

Comment: @WhozCraig: If a C++ exception (e.g. `std::bad_alloc`, `std::invalid_argument`, `std::runtime_error`, ...) is thrown from the "core" C++ code and is caught in a `try/catch` block in a COM method body, would you put the COM server in a special _"invalid state"_ and make the next method calls fail, or would you just map the exception to a failure `HRESULT` and continue serving your clients?

Comment: The severity of a caught exception can only be assessed in context. Whether this puts the COM server into an unrecoverable failure mode or not has to be decided for each invocation. When using C++ exceptions it is often helpful to implement the *strong guarantee*, i.e. an operation either runs to completion or rolls back all transient state modifications on failure.

Comment: Windows Explorer has counter-measures against badly behaving shell extensions, it is not going to let one crash the entire process.  That doesn't mean you should intentionally give it a hard time, just catch the exception and return an HRESULT.

What you can take a shortcut on is the fidelity of the HRESULT.  Explorer won't display a  detailed error dialog when an extension fails.  So just catch std::exception and return E_FAIL.  Helps you get rid of that ugly macro soup.  If you want to make errors diagnosable then you'll have to take care of logging yourself.

Comment: There are some good points in these comments. If you write some answers, I'd like to give you deserved credit by up-voting them. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never let exceptions propagate across COM boundary, otherwise the behavior is undefined and may include your C++ runtime `terminate()` being called, the process going nuts and other nice bonuses. Just don't do it. Even if you "tested" it in some configuration - it's still undefined behavior and will silently break should minor environment or implementation changes occur.

You should catch and translate all C++ exceptions into `HRESULT`s and optionally set `IErrorInfo` with details. You can do so with macros wrapping each COM server method implementation  or by copy-pasting this code everywhere - guess which is more maintainable.

The idea with driving the server into "invalid" state may make sense in some extreme situations but I can't imagine them at the moment. I guess it's not a universal solution. In general cases if you have exception safe code you shouldn't need this at all.

Comment: There's an interesting reading here: [**How to turn off the exception handler that COM "helpfully" wraps around your server**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/01/20/10117963.aspx); seems like a _fail fast_ approach.

Comment: @Mr.C64: No, that's another thing, it kicks in for structured exceptions only, not for C++ exceptions - the latter will just cause `terminate()` being called.

Comment: I'm not sure you're right... Consider: _"On the other hand a 'nonfatal' exception is something like a C++ exception or a CLR exception. You probably want an unhandled C++ or CLR exception to crash your server, too; after all, it would have crashed your program if it weren't running as a server. Therefore, my personal recommendation is to use COMGLB_EXCEPTION_DONOT_HANDLE_ANY whenever possible."_

Comment: @Mr.C64: I guess you could just test it. I haven't tested it explicitly myself but from my experience if you have C++ runtime loaded and an "unhandled" C++ exception occurs then it is first "handled" by C++ runtime by calling `terminate()` and so COM wrappers will have no chances to be run.